# Including .bat extension when calling Java Web Service

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services, batch-file

I am calling a Java Web Service using an ASP.NET Web Service. The Java Web Service executes the batch file that user indicates in the URL (e.g `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfile/test.bat`).

The ASP.NET Web Service acts as an API and should call the Java Web Service and return the data that is returned by the Java Web Service when I type the URL `http://localhost:62198/api/runbatchfile/test.bat` when ASP.NET Web Service is run.

However, I am not able to retrieve and display the data using ASP.NET Web Service and I feel that this is caused by the .bat extension. When I call a Java web service which has no parameters or has parameters which involves only numbers, this ASP.NET Web Service works however I am unable to get the results when an extension is involved.

The result i should be getting is `{"Result": true}` if batch file is executed and `{"Result": false}` if batch file is not executed. However, I get an empty `{}`. But the Java Web Service correctly displays the result when I run it. Only the ASP.NET Web Service is not able to read the data from the Java Web Service and display it.

What are the code that I should add so that the .bat extension is included too? Someone please do help me thank you so much in advance.

Here is what I have done so far:

**JAVA CODE**

**BatchFileController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile/{param:.+}")
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) {
RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
return rbf.runBatch(fileName);
}
```

**ResultFormat.java**

```
private boolean result;

public ResultFormat(boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

    String var = fileName;
    String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/" + var);
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        return new ResultFormat(exitVal == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResultFormat(false);
    }
```

**ASP.NET CODE**

**TestController.cs**

```
private TestClient testClient = new TestClient();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await testClient.runbatchfile(fileName);
            var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestVariable>(result);
            return Json(resultDTO);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = "Server is not running";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
    }
```

**TestVariable.cs**

```
public class TestVariable
{
    public static int fileName { get; set; }
}
```

**TestClient.cs**

```
public class TestClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static TestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> runbatchfile(string fileName)
    {
        var endpoint = string.Format("runbatchfile/{0}", fileName);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: `.bat` is a Windows batch file extension (so is `.cmd`) so you could be running into permissions issues. Unclear in your post if your Java WS can actually run the batch file itself (first test). Also, what is the (error) response you get from `HttpClient` (probably need to modify your Java WS to return error/exception info during debugging)?

Comment: Hi, Java WS able to run batch file

Comment: No error info, i just get an empty bracket `{}` as result

Comment: Is `TestController.GET` being invoked when you call the URL? is the parameter being populated?

Comment: TestController.GET should get invoked.

Comment: I think the problem is the .bat extension. When i use this codes to call a java WS with no parameters or with integer parameter, it works. It only does not work when i call java WS with parameter that include .bat extension

Answer (score 2):

Adding the ".bat" extension to the URL may not be the best approach here. This extension will not be recognized by the Web server and you will need to do some tweaking to allow it, also it might lead to some security issues out of your control because a .bat file is considered as an executable file.

In fact, if you know the file is always a ".bat" file, can't you just omit the extension from the URL altogether and have something like this:

```
http://localhost:62198/api/runbatchfile/test
```

Then you just add it in your code:

**JAVA CODES**

**BatchFileController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile/{param:.+}")
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch(fileName);
}
```

**ResultFormat.java**

```
private boolean result;

public ResultFormat(boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

    String var = fileName + ".bat";
    String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/" + var);
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        return new ResultFormat(exitVal == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResultFormat(false);
    }
```

**ASP.NET CODES**

**TestController.cs**

```
private TestClient testClient = new TestClient();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await testClient.runbatchfile(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
            var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestVariable>(result);
            return Json(resultDTO);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = "Server is not running";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
    }
```

**TestVariable.cs**

```
public class TestVariable
{
    public static int fileName { get; set; }
}
```

**TestClient.cs**

```
public class TestClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static TestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> runbatchfile(string fileName)
    {
        var endpoint = string.Format("runbatchfile/{0}", fileName);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

**A better solution**

In fact the problem is not the extension but the "point" that you have in your filename, so if you would need to also specify the type of file you could add another url parameter to do so, something like this:

```
http://localhost:62198/api/runbatchfile/test/bat
http://localhost:62198/api/runbatchfile/test/exe
http://localhost:62198/api/runbatchfile/test/cmd
```

The first parameter is the filename and the second is the extension, then in your controller actions you just generate the full filename using these two parameters:

```
[...]
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(String fileName, String ext) {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch(fileName, ext);
}

[...]
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName, String ext) {

    String var = fileName + "." + ext;
    [...]
}
```

And in your ASP.NET client:

```
var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Replace(".", String.Empty);

var result = await 
        testClient.runbatchfile(file, ext);
```